# How to read HTML files with ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Tags: c#, excel, aceoledb

I was trying to read .xls files with Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. I could able to read some of the files but some of them turned out to be html files with .xls extension and throw this error: `"External table is not in the expected format."` These HTML files have a scheme like this:

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" charset="utf-8"> 
  <meta name="ProgId" content="Excel.Sheet">
  <meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Excel 11">
  <title>Document and Custom Property </title>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><o:CustomDocumentProperties><o:BUSINESSGROUP dt:dt="string">CHANNELA</o:BUSINESSGROUP><o:BUSINESSGROUPID dt:dt="string">2</o:BUSINESSGROUPID></o:CustomDocumentProperties></xml><![endif]-->
 </head>
 <body>
 ...
 </body>
</html>
```

I changed my connection string to 
`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=file.xls;Extended Properties="HTML Import"` in order to read HTML files. However, it works very slow. Besides it skips `<div>` or other tags and reads only from formal `<td>` tags. But Excel 2013 can open such an HTML file very quickly and doesn't skip any HTML tag content.

How can I read such HTML files as Excel reads?

Comment: Perhaps try `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=file.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml"`?

Comment: It is `Excel 12.0 Xml` which generates `External table...` error.

Comment: Would you consider writing code to create an Excel Application instance, open the files in the application instance, and then saving a copy as `.xlsx`? After that, they should be in standard Office XML format, and you should be able to connect to them using the standard connection string.

Comment: Do you mean using `Excel Interop`?

Comment: Yes. At least to convert the files into a common format.

Comment: Do you think third party packages like ExcelDataReader, closedXML, NPoi, LinqToExcel can read Excel produced HTML files?